# postgresql join and insert

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join, insertion-order

I have two tables, account_subscriptions and order_item and I wrote this query:

```
Select a1.accounts_id,sum(a2.quantity * a2.unit_price) as MRR
from account_subscriptions a1 
inner join order_item a2 on a1.subscription_id = a2.account_subscriptions_id 
group by a1.accounts_id;
```

With this code I am able find the total_bill as MRR along with its corresponding account_id. But now I want to put it in an existing table named summary, where there is already columns along with account_id and MRR column which is empty.

I want to put the values of MRR I got from my query into the MRR column with matching the corresponding account_id of summary table and account_subscriptions table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating, not inserting:

```
with c as (
Select a1.accounts_id,sum(a2.quantity * a2.unit_price) as MRR
from account_subscriptions a1 
inner join order_item a2 on a1.subscription_id = a2.account_subscriptions_id 
group by a1.accounts_id
)
update summary s set MRR = c.MRR 
from c
where c.accounts_id = s.accounts_id
```

**update** reconciling your comments, to wrap it up to function use

```
create function fn_name_here() returns int as
$$
begin
    with c as (
    Select a1.accounts_id,sum(a2.quantity * a2.unit_price) as MRR
    from account_subscriptions a1 
    inner join order_item a2 on a1.subscription_id = a2.account_subscriptions_id 
    group by a1.accounts_id
    )
    update summary s set MRR = c.MRR 
    from c
    where c.accounts_id = s.accounts_id;
return 0;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
```

Please start reading and practicing SQL and/or plpgsql - just wrapping the code in function does not make much sense. With no logic inside...

Comment: can u tel me how can i frame it in a procedure named calculate_mrr

Comment: In postgresql procedure...Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi i have another requirement with this query that needs insertion also in the summary table if the accounts_id is not already present in it then the accounts_id and mrr both should be inserted as new record

Comment: hi, please think about what has to be done and when you feel you understand the task, google for a solution. If you don't find it, please click "Ask question" button and post the question to community

Comment: i have been trying from yesterday,googled also and tried atleast 6-7 different methods but one error is coming with this method

Comment: cool. so go ahead, ask a question. comments are used for commenting, posts for questios and answers

Comment: or if u just know the answer you can update my answer on this page only. what say?

Comment: SO is not online support. the idea is to have a working solution for OP problem. If problem keep changing it requires new and new post, not mutating the original post